# How to prevent article titles to become links in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am making a website in Drupal 8. I made a new content type 'News item' and a view called 'News' that shows all news items as a blog page.

All news items are made small enough, so no linking to full article through article title is needed.

I am pretty new to Drupal and I can not find where or how to switch this off. Could anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy:

**1.** edit view

**2.** FORMAT > Show > Fields

**3.** FIELDS > Content Title > uncheck "Link to the Content"

Your preview should now show your title with no link

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Thanks! I found out that there is also a special page for Drupal, so I had put my question there as well. Same answer, little more detailed: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192631/how-to-prevent-article-titles-to-become-links/192749#192749